# Scrapy: Data retrieved with xpath in shell but not in item

Tags: shell, xpath, web-scraping, scrapy, web-crawler

I am building a simple web scraper using scrapy to get the results of a football team from the BBC website. The relevant HTML from the page (http://www.bbc.com/sport/football/teams/bolton-wanderers/results) is this:

```
<tr class="report" id="match-row-EFBO755964">
  <td class="statistics show" title="Show latest match stats">
    <button>Show</button> 
  </td> 
  <td class="match-competition"> Championship  </td>  
  <td class="match-details teams"> 
    <p> 
      <span class="team-home teams"> <a href="/sport/football/teams/huddersfield-town">Huddersfield</a> </span>   
      <span class="score"> <abbr title="Score"> 2-1 </abbr> </span>   
      <span class="team-away teams"> <a href="/sport/football/teams/bolton-wanderers">Bolton</a> </span>   
    </p> 
  </td> 
  <td class="match-date"> Sun 28 Dec </td>   
  <td class="time">  Full time  </td>   
  <td class="status">   <a class="report" href="/sport/football/30566395">Report</a>
  </td> 
</tr>
```

When I try scraping using the scrapy shell, this is the output:

```
$ scrapy shell http://www.bbc.com/sport/football/teams/bolton-wanderers/results

>>> response.selector.xpath('//tr[@class="report"]/td[@class="match-date"]/text()').extract()
[u' Sun 28 Dec ', u' Fri 26 Dec ', u' Fri 19 Dec ', u' Sat 13 Dec ',...]
```

However, when I use the same xpath in my spider, I'm unable to get these dates.
Here is the item:

```
class resultsItem(scrapy.Item):
  date          = scrapy.Field()
  homeTeam      = scrapy.Field()
  score         = scrapy.Field()
  awayTeam      = scrapy.Field()
```

Here is the spider:

```
class resultsSpider(scrapy.Spider):
name = "results"
allowed_domains = ["bbc.com"]
start_urls = ["http://www.bbc.com/sport/football/teams/bolton-wanderers/results"]

def parse(self, response):
    for sel in response.xpath('//tr[@class="report"]'):
        game = resultsItem()
        game['homeTeam'] = sel.xpath('td[@class="match-details teams"]/p/span[@class="team-home teams"]/a/text()').extract()
        game['score'] = sel.xpath('td[@class="match-details teams"]/p/span[@class="score"]/abbr/text()').extract()
        game['awayTeam'] = sel.xpath('td[@class="match-details teams"]/p/span[@class="team-away teams"]/a/text()').extract()
        game['date'] = response.xpath('td[@class="match-date"]/text()').extract()

        yield game
```

And lastly, the outputted JSON:

```
[{"date": [], "awayTeam": ["Bolton"], "homeTeam": ["Huddersfield"], "score": [" 2-1 "]},
{"date": [], "awayTeam": ["Blackburn"], "homeTeam": ["Bolton"], "score": [" 2-1 "]},...
```

Why cannot I get the date even though using the same xpath in the shell gives me it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shouldn't it be

```
game['date'] = sel.xpath('td[@class="match-date"]/text()').extract()
```

instead of

```
game['date'] = response.xpath('td[@class="match-date"]/text()').extract()
```

as you are in this loop

```
for sel in response.xpath('//tr[@class="report"]'):
```

Comment: Yes... thank you, I really just needed an extra pair of eyes to review my code, easier to look over these kind of things than I'd like to admit!